# Redirecting to extension resource in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xss

For development purposes I am trying to build an extension that redirects all requests matching a regex to a specific page. The problem is that the firefox API does not seem to do what is advertised at the documentation of `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener`. Here is a simplified version of the extension:

*manifest.js*

```
{
    "applications": {
      "gecko": {
        "id": "addon@example.com",
          "strict_min_version": "42.0",
          "strict_max_version": "50.*",
          "update_url": "https://example.com/updates.json"
      }
    },

    "name": "Developer",
    "version": "0.1.26",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "A script useful for development.",
    "icons": {"16": "logo16.png",
              "48": "logo48.png",
              "128": "logo128.png"},
    "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "web_accessible_resources": ["hello.html"],
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking"
    ]
}
```

*background.js*

```
// I found somewhere that onBeforeSendHeader it should work but it doesn't.
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(details) {
    var redirect;
    if (details.url.match(/example\.com/)) {
      redirect = chrome.extension.getURL("hello.html");
      console.log("Redirecting:", details.url, "->", redirect);
      return {redirectUrl: redirect};
      }
    console.log("Requesting:",details.url);
  }, {urls: [
    "<all_urls>"
  ]}, ["blocking"]);
```

*hello.html*

```
<html>
    <head>It works</head>
    <body>And it's not apache!</body>
</html>
```

In short it redirects anything fetched from `example.com` to an extension resource `hello.html`.

So I go to about:config and set `security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy` to `false`. Then I go to `about:debugging` and load the extension. Then I open the browser console `Tools -> Web Developer -> Browser Console`. Finally I go to example.com. I should be getting the contents of `hello.html` but instead I get nothing (white screen) and in the browser console I get:

```
Redirecting: "http://example.com/" -> "moz-extension://ce33a9b5-2c20-ed41-b8aa-f52143783c38/hello.html"
Security Error: Content at http://example.com/ may not load or link to file:///path/to/extension/hello.html.
```

I need the extension for personal development purposes so I don't mind changing `about:config`.

EDIT: if i change the redirect url to something on the web and `onBeforeReqeuest` to `onBeforeSendHeaders` everything works:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
  function(details) {
    var redirect;
    if (details.url.match(/example\.com/)) {
      redirect = "https://www.google.com"; // chrome.extension.getURL("hello.html");
      console.log("Redirecting:", details.url, "->", redirect);
      return {redirectUrl: redirect};
      }
    console.log("Requesting:",details.url);
  }, {urls: [
    "<all_urls>"
  ]}, ["blocking"]);
```

Edit2: Sorry that would be a WebExtension (although I think it is obvious from the fact that there is a `manifest.json` file instead of an `install.rdf`). Also the documentation [onBeforeRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onBeforeRequest) at the `addListener` section states:

> Returns: webRequest.BlockingResponse. If "blocking" is specified in the "extraInfoSpec" parameter, the event listener should return an object of this type.

And then in the [BlockingResponse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/WebRequest/BlockingResponse) docs:

> redirectUrl Optional
>       string. Only used as a response to the onBeforeRequest and onHeadersReceived events. If set, the original request is prevented
>   from being sent/completed and is instead redirected to the given URL.
>   Redirections to non-HTTP schemes such as data: are allowed. Redirects
>   initiated by a redirect action use the original request method for the
>   redirect, with one exception: If the redirect is initiated at the
>   onHeadersReceived stage, then the redirect will be issued using the
>   GET method.

Comment: I really don't understand why this was downvoted...

Comment: While I did not downvote, I might be tempted to do so because: A) You state that something is not performing per documentation, but don't link to the documentation; B) You don't tell us what [type of Firefox extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons) you are developing (we can guess, but we should not have to).

Comment: @fakedrake I'm experiencing the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope. For what it's worth it worked fine on chrome back the IIRC

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me for both chrome and firefox.

```
    let { tabId } = details;
    let redirectUrl = chrome.extension.getURL('hello.html');
    if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("firefox") > -1) {
        chrome.tabs.update(tabId, {
            url: redirectUrl
        })
        return {
            cancel: true
        }
    } else return { redirectUrl }
```